# Is there a function to update a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to R and have tried looking for the correct way to write this. I apologize if this is a relatively rudimentary question!

```
all_loan_offers <- function(df) {
  
  df$decision <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    
    income <- df$income[i]
    c_record <- df$c_record[i]
    years <- df$years[i]
    decision <- df$decision[i]
    
    if (income > 80000){
      decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income < 40000 & c_record == FALSE){
      decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income < 40000 & c_record == TRUE){
      decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income >= 40000 & income <= 80000 & years > 3){
      decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else {
      decision[i] <- "Reject"
    }
    return(df)
  } 
}

applicants_info <- data.frame(income = c(40000, 80000, 25000, 70000),
                              c_record = c(F, T, T, F),
                              years = c(2, 10, 3, 6),
                              stringsAsFactors = F) 


all_loan_offers(applicants_info)
```

all_loan_offers then returns the applicants_info df, but my objective is to return an updated data frame with a 4th column to "Admit" or "Reject" based on my if-else ladder.

Many thanks - any help at all would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why two lines for `income` < 4000 when both lead to "Admit"? You are only rejecting applicants with income between 40000 and 80000 and years < 3. You only need one if statement for "Reject" since everything else is "Admit".

Comment: @dcarlson you're right - thank you. The second line for income < 40000 should lead to "Reject."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the local `decision` variable inside the for loop. When you set `df$decision <- c()` you are not doing anything, `c()` is NULL. You can set the initial value of all rows to `"Reject"` and then admit when conditions are met (dropping the last `else { ... }`).

```r
all_loan_offers <- function(df) {
  
  df$decision <- "Reject"
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    
    income <- df$income[i]
    c_record <- df$c_record[i]
    years <- df$years[i]
    
    if (income > 80000){
      df$decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income < 40000 & c_record == FALSE){
      df$decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income < 40000 & c_record == TRUE){
      df$decision[i] <- "Admit"
    } else if(income >= 40000 & income <= 80000 & years > 3){
      df$decision[i] <- "Admit"
    }
  } 
  df
}

applicants_info <- data.frame(income = c(40000, 80000, 25000, 70000),
                              c_record = c(F, T, T, F),
                              years = c(2, 10, 3, 6),
                              stringsAsFactors = F) 


all_loan_offers(applicants_info)
#>   income c_record years decision
#> 1  40000    FALSE     2   Reject
#> 2  80000     TRUE    10    Admit
#> 3  25000     TRUE     3    Admit
#> 4  70000    FALSE     6    Admit
```

EDIT: Note that you can omit the for loop entirely, too. R is great because it operates on whole vectors of values. You can create numeric index from a logical vector and insert conformal vectors of values (thanks to "recycling" of the right hand side)

```
all_loan_offers <- function(df) {
  df$decision <- "Reject"
  df$decision[which(df$income > 80000)] <- "Admit"
  df$decision[which(df$income < 40000 & !df$c_record)] <- "Admit"
  df$decision[which(df$income >= 40000 & df$income <= 80000 & df$years > 3)] <- "Admit"
  df
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew - this works! I appreciate it so much! Have a great evening!

Comment: note that you can omit the for loop entirely, too. R is great because it operates on whole vectors of values. You can create numeric index from a logical vector and insert conformal vectors of values (thanks to "recycling" of the right hand side)

all_loan_offers <- function(df) {
  df$decision <- "Reject";
  df$decision[which(df$income > 80000)] <- "Admit";
  df$decision[which(df$income < 40000 & !df$c_record)] <- "Admit";
  df$decision[which(df$income >= 40000 & df$income <= 80000 & df$years > 3)] <- "Admit";
  df
}